# Keyboard stuck on Windows Key when Asleep

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, peripherals

I have Windows 8 Enterprise x64 and a Razer BlackWidow Ultimate 2013 Edition.

I am using a Dell XPS 9000.

Whenever I leave my computer alone for a short period of time while it is locked, about 80% of the time one of two things happens.

1) My windows key gets stuck which means that when I type the 'u' in my password the computer starts the 'Ease of Access' functionality of the start up menu.  In order to solve this, I have to hit the windows key a few times and then it starts working normally.

2) A key is repeated infinitely in the password field.  In order to solve this I have to unplug and replug my keyboard.  Then it works as would be expected.

Neither of these two things happen if I lock my computer and then immediately unlock it.  It is only when I leave it along for a period and the screen turns off.  I have tried the simple things already (reinstalling the driver, evaluating my macros, etc.) but I really can't figure out what is going on.  Something similar used to happen with my old Logitech keyboard as well but I can't remember the details.  I would really like to get this fixed but it just doesn't seem very clear what is causing the issue.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

First, attach the keyboard to another computer, or even another keyboard to that computer, let them lock after leaving them alone and see what happens.

If you've put a different keyboard on that computer, and nothing happens, you can classify the keyboard as the problem, if you issue returns, you can rule out the keyboard.

Also is the keyboard USB or PS2.